# Filtered Gallery for Portfolio rearranging to display inline?

Tags: jquery, html, portfolio

I'm creating a filtered gallery using Bootstrap's 3 column portfolio framework. The portfolio filters everything out, but it doesn't rearrange the div items to display inline, it just removes the items that don't have the same data-rel instead of removing and then rearranging so that there's no empty spaces between items.

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".filter").click(function(){
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
        $(".work").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $(".portfolio-item").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale').sort();
            $(".work").fadeTo(300, 1);
        }, 300); 
    });
});
```

I tried to add the .sort function, but nothing changed, so I'm assuming I have it in the wrong spot or there's more code needed?

```
  HTML

        <section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Portfolio</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">A showcase of my work.</h3>
                <div class="tabs">
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" href="" data-rel="all">ALL</button>
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" data-rel="web">Web Design</button>
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" data-rel="graphics">Graphic Design</button>
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" data-rel="branding">Branding</button>
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" data-rel="photography">Photography</button>
                    <button class="btn filter" id="filt" data-rel="motion">Motion Graphics</button>

                </div> 
                <br>
            </div>
    <div class="work">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item web scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item graphics scale  tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item branding scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item motion scale tile all">
                <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/1.jpg">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item motion scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item motion scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item photography scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item graphics scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item web scale tile all">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--WORK-->
    <!-- /.row -->
    <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should also post your HTML, so one could play with it.

Comment: Please see my edit ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a button of your works, it hide alls and then shows the items of the selected category.

Example: a click on "Web Desing" shows the first and last items.

If I clearly understand the problem... The last should appear to the right of the first... Not under it.

That is because it is "prisoneer" of it's `<div class="row">`.
In this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JbBxjd?editors=1010), I only removed those in your HTML.
It's the only change I made.
It can now "float" freely to the right of the previous element.

Is it the desired result?

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was that but then I wasn't sure if it would affect the responsiveness, works perfectly though! Thanks!